# How to inverse behaviour of a switch?

Tags: switches, passive-components

I have a sustain pedal (which is just a momentary switch!) with the wrong polarity (according to the device I'm using it with) :

- circuit is **CLOSED** when pedal is **pressed**
- circuit is **OPEN** when pedal is **released**

I would like the opposite.

**Is there an electronical solution to invert the behaviour of such a switch, with only passive components (without having to use a battery-powered component, etc.) ?**

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: If you're lucky, then the internal switch will have both  "Normally Opened" and "Normally Closed" contacts.  If this is the case, you'll just have to move the wire to the other connection.  Are you willing to take it apart and see?  If so, post a picture :)

Comment: Some musical stuff can auto-sense what type of switch you've plugged into it.  Whatever state it sees when it powers on is assumed to be inactive.  You can test this by holding the pedal down while turning the thing on that it's connected to.  If it magically fixes itself, that's probably what's happening.

Comment: Worse comes to worse use a transistor configured as an inverting switch. You could slam that onto an arduino.

Comment: An electronic solution would depend on what the switch plugs into.  You could do it with a relay and a power supply to turn the relay on and off with the switch.

Comment: @bitsmack I corrected my question (i checked with a multimeter: circuit is CLOSED when pedal is pressed!) and added 2 pictures of what's inside the pedal :) Unfortunately, no "Normally Opened/Closed" contacts...

Comment: @AaronD I already tried this, but unfortunately it doesn't work with my DX7 or my Juno 106: they don't auto-sense what type of switch is plugged

Comment: @mcmiln an *arduino+power supply* would be more expensive than a new sustain pedal with the correct polarity (around $10-$15)

Comment: There is the option of a mechanical solution. A spring or similar continually applies pressure to the switch until a foot relieves the pressure through a cantilever.

Comment: Are you *sure* that you indeed have a problem? Many instruments that accept pedal inputs will detect whether the switch is open at power-up. If it's closed, they'll assume that you have a NC pedal. Perhaps your instrument/effects box already does that?

Comment: @KubaOber nor my DX7 nor my Juno106 do detect wheter the switch is open or close at power-up

Comment: :( Sorry to hear that. It's one of those features that usually get implemented if there's a CPU, and if someone heard of the trick or re-discovered it. Probably vintage instruments predate the widespread knowledge of this approach.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fhKRmF.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This might work.
Before trying this, check the equipment it needs to work with and measure the voltage across the open switch. If you see 3 to 5V, then the chance of this working increases. Otherwise, it may not be worth the trouble to try. Connect the plus side to the plus of the diagram.

When SW1 is open, R1 conducts, Q1 turns on, voltage between + and - becomes around 0.7V (if current from equipment not too high). There is a reasonable chance that the equipment would interpret 0.7V as switch closed.

When SW1 is closed, base of Q1 is grounded, some small amount of current drains through R1. If the source resistance is small compare to R1, the voltage is high.

May need to experiment with different value of R1 but most likely something around 10K to 100K.

Comment: Waw, this looks great! Before testing, what's the % of risk of damaging my synths with this test ? 1% 10e-7 %?
I have now ordered some 2N3904 on ebay!

Comment: There is almost no chance of damaging the equipment. This circuit has no power source. Basically, it just changes resistance. If you look at just a switch, it changes resistance from 0 to infinity. So the equipment must be able to tolerate the change. I probably shouldn't even said "base is grounded". When SW1 is closed, base-emitter of Q1 is shorted, turning it off. Then the circuit becomes like it is just R1 alone. If R1 is large (like 100K), it should look like an open switch to the equipment.

Comment: Just went to my usual fablab this evening, and discovered they had lots of unused 2N3904 and 10K resistors. I tried your schematics ... and it works with my synth now :) :)

Comment: Sidenote: Unfortunately doesn't work with my Roland Juno 106 yet... Would there be more chance to work with a 100K resistor than the 10K I used?  What voltage instead of 0.7V would there be with 100K / 10K?

Comment: 100K can make a difference, because the larger resistance is more similar to an open switch. It takes around 0.6-0.7V of \$V_{BE}\$ to turn on the transistor. The on voltage would stay at around 0.7V unless the current sourced by the equipment is too large.

Comment: With 100K, this works with both DX7 and Juno 106 :) Thanks again @rioraxe !

Answer (score 1):

That type of switch is normally open only.  It works by pressing a conductive pad across the exposed PCB traces.

There is no passive way that I know of to allow current when the controlling device blocks it and then block it when the controlling device allows it.  At best, you'd end up allowing current all the time or not at all.

If you're okay with potentially breaking the one you have, you might try a mechanical solution.  Somehow, press the pad against the PCB using something other than the pedal, and use the pedal to release it.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

The simplest method is to use a relay!
Connect your switch to the relays coil pins and circuit that you want to control to the pins that are normally open. Thats it!

Answer (score 1):

If you hold the pedal down while Turning the device on it will switch the polarity. Almost all keyboards have this behaviour.

Comment: Are you suggesting the OP invert how they use their pedal, rather than modifying it to work how they want (which is the intent of the question)? Also, note that this is a 4 year old question.

Comment: @Devin, you're right, it can work with many keyboards (I upvoted), but not all. Thus my question.

Comment: @Daniel even if it is an old question, any new good answer is always welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

I was thinking a bit more about this problem. There is no need for arduino/uC/external supplies and so on.
 The solution is as simple as it can be:

You need to get SPST switch which is NC (normally closed). You will need to resolder it in the place of the original one. Here are some [SPST NC](http://www.digikey.com/product-search/en?pv130=1&FV=fff40011%2Cfff80061&mnonly=0&newproducts=0&ColumnSort=0&page=1&quantity=0&ptm=0&fid=0&pageSize=25) which I found from my quick search. Make sure it can get back to its original posistion and you shall have no other problems.

Some images:

 You have this kind of switch (call it button). It is normally OPEN. When the pedal is pressed it gets CLOSED.[image: SPST NO]

Instead, for your needs, you need button which is normally CLOSED, then when switched it gets normally OPEN.

[image: SPST NC]

 I hope this is the simplest solution available. Get the proper button and there you have it.

Comment: Thanks! Do you have a photo of such a component? Do you think I could mount it easily on the current PCB? (See my question - edited - with some photos of inside the pedal / PCB )

Comment: Yes, I could not upload it in the question. Here you go http://media.digikey.com/photos/Judco%20Mfg%20Photos/50-0014-00_sml.jpg . Add the grey button on top of the yellow one if you like (more bounce).

Comment: Thanks @Triak, but how to mount this on my current PCB?

Comment: You will need to remove the existing PCB. You will need to resolder the new switch (pin1 goes to black or white, pin2 goes to remaining wire).

Comment: Then @Triak I think this will be more expensive (making a new PCB) than to buy another pedal (10$)

Comment: You do not need PCB to fix the switch in place and solder it.

Comment: My concern with using a pushbutton like the one linked to is getting the travel right.  I think it would make more sense to use a microswitch like [this one](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/V-10G3-1C24-K/SW1068-ND/369917) that has a long lever that can be adjusted.  The only gotcha here is I think the minimum height of these is around 1/2", so that might not fit inside the pedal -- hard to tell from the photo.  I agree with others there is no need to get rid of the PCB, one can just epoxy a switch on top of the current contacts and wire to the existing traces.